# Knockout subscribe is not called when changing observable array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Take this code:

```js
var koEvents = new ko.subscribable();

var viewModel = function() {
   var self = this;

   self.data = ko.observableArray([{
      valid: true
   }, {
      valid: true
   }]);

   self.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
      var isValid = true;
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.data(), function(item) {
         console.log(item.valid);
         if (!item.valid) {
            isValid = false;
            return;
         };
      });
      return isValid;
   }, this).subscribe(function(newValue) {
      alert("Subscribe called!");
      koEvents.notifySubscribers(newValue, "dataChanged");
   }.bind(this));

   return {
      data: self.data,
      isValid: self.isValid,
   };
}

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("container"));

vm.data()[0].valid = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
   <div data-bind="text: isValid ? 'valid': 'invalid'">
   </div>
</div>
```

I have two questions...

1. Why is `self.isValid` not called, when I do this `vm.data()[0].valid = false;`?
2. Why is subscribe (`alert("Subscribe called!");`) not called when initially isValid is true and later set to false? I expect this to be called twice in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with that code, but the main issue in relation to what you've asked is that changing a non-observable property (`valid`) on an object in an observable array is not changing the observable array, just a property on an object within it. So naturally there's no notification. If you want notification, you'll need to watch the `valid` property (which in turn means it will have to be observable).

Other issues:

1. One of the issues with Knockout is that it *sometimes* unwraps observables/computeds for you, but it *doesn't* if they're part of an expression — you have to do it (with `()`):

   ```html
   <div data-bind="text: isValid() ? 'valid': 'invalid'"></div>
   <!-- ------------------------^^                          -->
   ```

   Your code was testing whether `isValid` (not `isValid()`) was truthy. Which it always is, because it's a function reference.

   KO only does the automatic unwrapping for you when the identifier isn't part of an expression. For instance, this works:

   ```html
   <!-- Works -->
   <div data-bind="visible: isValid">...</div>
   ```

   but this doesn't:

   ```html
   <!-- Doesn't work -->
   <div data-bind="visible: !isValid">...</div>
   ```

   (when `isValid` is an observable/computed).
2. You're setting `self.isValid` to the *subscription handle*, not the computed, because you've overdone your chaining. :-) You need to complete the assignment after the end of the call to `computed`, and *then* subscribe:

   ```
   self.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
      // ...
   }, this); // <=== End the assignment here
   self.isValid.subscribe(function(newValue) {
      // ...
   }.bind(this));
   ```
3. You're using `self = this`, but then also passing `this` to `computed` and using `bind` with `subscribe`. This is harmless, but pointless. One or the other is all you need.
4. There's no need to create a new, separate object as the return value of your VM constructor; you already have an object (the one created by `new`).

Here's an example with those various changes. The `valid` property on the first entry is set to `false` after 800ms:

```js
var koEvents = new ko.subscribable();

var viewModel = function() {
   this.data = ko.observableArray([{
      valid: ko.observable(true)
   }, {
      valid: ko.observable(true)
   }]);

   this.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
      var isValid = true;
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.data(), function(item) {
         console.log(item.valid());
         if (!item.valid()) {
            isValid = false;
            return;
         };
      });
      return isValid;
   }, this);
   this.isValid.subscribe(function(newValue) {
      alert("Subscribe called!");
      koEvents.notifySubscribers(newValue, "dataChanged");
   });
}

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("container"));

setTimeout(function() {
  vm.data()[0].valid(false);
}, 800);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
   <div data-bind="text: isValid() ? 'valid' : 'invalid'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! ... well I was told to use Stack Snippets instead of Fiddle ... so normally I would update the Fiddle an post the new fiddle-link in "answer" ... but I can't see how I can update the code without doing it in the question?

Comment: @MojoDK: You can't. When it's unavoidable to do that, your best bet is to just put a second snippet under the first saying "I've tried to do what answer X says but it's still not working:" or similar. (Then once there's an answer covering what's necessary, you can remove it again.) It's important when doing that to limit it to the issues that were already present (questions aren't meant to be moving targets). In this case, they were, so it would have been fine. Glad that helped!